# Civimail URLs not working

Tags: civimail

I've just sent a newsletter and had replies telling me the links to content on our website aren't working. I've checked and they're not, they're going to CiviCRM in the Wordpress plugins folder, and then different URLs that look something like: "url.php?u=60&qid=1389" (its different depending on the original URL). When you click one of these links in a draft email they go to a blank page.

Anyone had something similar? Any known fixes?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste the url?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check the resource URL and directory settings. If the resource url for CiviCRM is not set properly then the url build while mailing is send will be wrong.

When you have mailing with track url enabled than CiviCRM rewrites the url to 'url.php?u=60&qid=1389' so that it can track the click. But when you click on the url from email it gets in CiviCRM and then based on url params it redirects to correct url.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Hi, OK thanks. As far as I can see its set correctly, but I will try again.